# Nullablle<>'s and "null" in F#

Tags: f#

I'm calling functions in the XNA framework from F# that accept Nullable values. Now, in C#, you would just call:

```
foo(arg1, arg2, null, arg4)
```

Now, I tried that in F#, but it doesn't like it. It says: "Error 9 Type constraint mismatch. The type 'a is not compatible with type System.Nullable The type 'System.Nullable' does not have 'null' as a proper value."

I understand why this is happening, sort of, but it seems really inconvenient. All I'm doing now is, to make life easier, instead of repeatedly typing `(Nullable<Rectangle>)null` everytime I call the function, I just did `let nullRect = (Nullable<Rectangle>)null`, and use nullRect. This seems really stupid, especially since I'd have to do that for every nullable type I interact with. Is there a better, more idiomatic way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
[<GeneralizableValue>]
let nl<'a when 'a : struct
           and 'a : (new : unit -> 'a)
           and 'a :> System.ValueType> : System.Nullable<'a> =
  unbox null
```

Now you can use `nl` wherever you would have used `null` before.

**EDIT**

As Tomas notes, this can be written much more concisely as:

```
let nl = System.Nullable<_>()
```

Comment: As a side-note, this can be simplified to `[<GeneralizableValue>] let nl = System.Nullable<_>()`. F# can infer the rest of the signature.

Comment: That's really neat! I haven't had a chance to try out Tomas's abbreviation yet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Tomas - in fact, in that case, you don't even need the `[<GeneralizableValue>]` attribute; it looks like structs' default constructors are always generalizable.

Comment: That's even nicer! I'll need to look at the `GeneralizableValue` attribute in details one day...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use kvb's very clever answer, in many cases you can omit the specific type and just use `Nullable<_>()` - F# can infer what sort of Nullable you mean.