# Assignment to Nullable in F#

Tags: f#

I'm working with a library (WPF extended toolkit) where almost every property is a `Nullable<'T>`.  This makes it something of a pain everywhere to constantly have to write

```
checkbox.IsChecked <- new Nullable<bool>(true)
```

In C# this would convert implicitly.  Is there any way to mimic the same behavior in F#?  The most succinct option I've found is

```
checkbox.IsChecked <- unbox true
```

but that seems to generate more overhead in a tight loop (micro-optimization, but still), and even still it's less succinct than C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fix is to define a prefix operator:

```
let inline (!) (x: ^a) = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)

checkbox.IsChecked <- !true
```

Be aware that this shadows the de-referencing operator. If that's an issue you can pick a different symbol.

Comment: It's no more misleading than the built-in dereferencing operator, e.g.: `if !myboolref then ...`

Comment: So then I'll pick another symbol

Answer (score 9):

The `new` keyword is optional, and type inference will take care of the generic argument:

```
open System
checkbox.IsChecked <- Nullable true
```

If you prefer not to type ten extra keystrokes each time, you can declare a function as Carsten König described, but the declaration need not be as verbose as his:

```
let nl x = Nullable x
checkbox.IsChecked <- nl true
```

Answer (score 5):

have a look at this question: [Nullablle<>'s and "null" in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627425/nullablles-and-null-in-f?rq=1) - you can do the same to wrap any value in a generic way:

```
let nl (x : 'a) = 
   System.Nullable<'a> (x)
```

and just use it like this:

```
checkbox.IsChecked <- nl true;
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need to declare the type of the parameter, nor do you need a placeholder for the generic argument, nor do you need parentheses.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: yes but I kindof like the idea of giving the type-signatures to the top-level functions in a module/class/whatever. Even if the compiler can infer them the functions tend to be more readable - and yes this idea comes from Haskell and is possible non-idiomatic in F# (where point-free style is frowned upon) - still I find it usefull in non-tooltip-able environments ;) - and thank you for the comment and upvote